# Turning off 2.4GHz on Apple Airport Extreme

Tags: wifi, airport

If you turn off 2.4GHz in the Apple Airport Extreme, it pops up an alert that says

> Turning off 2.4GHz Wi-Fi networking on this base station can adversely affect the overall performance of your network.

I ignored the message and turned off 2.4GHz. I have not experienced any issues, but what "overall performance" problems can happen here? Is Apple referring to problems with range, device compatibility, or something else?

Comment: Likely just about compatibility since some older devices (like the iPhone 4) don't support 5GHz wireless. Furthermore, 2.4GHz provides better range, and devices tend to move towards the 2.4 when they are further away from the router or when the 5GHz band is plugged.